# Can I use domain controller as one of my nodes in my cluster environment?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, cluster, failovercluster

I want do some SQL Server failover cluster experiment on Windows 2008 R2 in VM. Now I created a domain controller(as DNS server too) **DC**. Also I created a server **server1** and added into the domain. Can I just use **DC and server1** to make the cluster? Or do I need to create another server **server2** and use **server1 and server2** to make my two-node cluster?

I'm new to cluster. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to use a domain controller as a cluster node, and in fact, there are [limitations even on standalone SQL Server installations on a DC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#DC_Support).

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes ONLY it should be OK. For Production, you should never mix SQL Server with any other application.